# How to weight observations in decision tree python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a data set with policies that run for different numbers of days.
The policies that run for more days have to have higher weight compared to the policies that run for less days.
Is there a way that I can do that in tree based models in python? Especially, decision tree model.

Every policy is 1 row.

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sample_weight` argument of the `fit()` function to weight your training samples.

As follow:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification()
weights = np.random.uniform(size=y.shape)

DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X, y, sample_weight=weights)
```